# Count within the aggregate SUM()

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, count, sum, sql-function

I have a table with 1000 rows. Columns exist are ID, DBID, TalkTime.

I am doing:

```
SELECT DBID, SUM(TalkTime)
FROM Incoming_Calls
GROUP BY DBID
```

This condenses down to approximely 18 rows.

I want to know how I can count the number of records present within each grouping. So for example DBID 105 has a sum of 526 which is made up of 395 records, DBID 104 has a sum of 124 made up using 241 of the records during the grouping.

Any ideas?

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 4):

Then use `COUNT()`

```
SELECT DBID, 
       COUNT(*) TotalRows, 
       SUM(TalkTime) TotalTalkTime
FROM   Incoming_Calls
GROUP  BY DBID
```

- [TSQL Aggregate Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DBID, SUM(TalkTime), COUNT(TalkTime) TalkTimeCount 
FROM Incoming_Calls 
GROUP BY DBID
```

OR, If you want to include null values count then you can you this

```
Select DBID, SUM(TalkTime), @@ROWCOUNT 
FROM Incoming_Calls 
GROUP BY DBID
```

Comment: Just noting that this option will return a count of those records that have non-null values for `TalkTime`, and @JW's will return a count of all records, regardless of whether there is a null for `TalkTime`.